# Convert timestamps from temporal series to the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame containing a timestamp every 5 minutes with a value for each ID. Now, I need to perform some analysis and I would like to plot all the time series on the same temporal time window.
My data frame is similar to this one:

```
ID      timestamp                           value
 12345    2017-02-09 14:35:00               60.0
 12345    2017-02-09 14:40:00               62.0
 12345    2017-02-09 14:45:00               58.0
 12345    2017-02-09 14:50:00               60.0
 54321    2017-03-09 13:35:00               50.0 
 54321    2017-03-09 13:40:00               58.0 
 54321    2017-03-09 13:45:00               59.0 
 54321    2017-03-09 13:50:00               61.0
```

For instance, in the xy axis, I need to use the x=0 value as the first timestamp for each ID, and the x=1 the second after 5 minutes, and so on.
Until now, I correctly resampled every 5 minutes with this code:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').resample('5T').mean().reset_index()
```

But, given the fact the every ID starts at different timestamps, I don't know how to modify the timestamps in order to use the first measured date of each ID as timestamp 0, and each next timestamp every 5 minutes as timestamp 1, timestamp 2, timestamp 3, ecc, in order to plot the series of each ID to confront them graphically. A sample final df may be:

```
 ID      timestamp       value
 12345    0               60.0
 12345    1               62.0
 12345    2               58.0
 12345    3               60.0
 54321    0               50.0 
 54321    1               58.0 
 54321    2               59.0 
 54321    3               61.0
```

Using this data frame, is is possible to plot all the series starting and finishing at the same point? Start at 0 and finish after 3 days.
How do I create such different timestamps and plot every series for each ID on the same figure?
Thankl you very much

Answer (score 0):

First create a new column with the timestamp number in 5 minutes intervals.

```
df['ts_number'] = df.groupby(['ID']).timestamp.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min())/pd.Timedelta(minutes=5))
```

If you know in advance that all your timestamps are in 5 minute intervalls and they are sorted, then you can also use

```
df['ts_number'] = df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()
```

Then plot the pivoted data:

```
df.pivot('ts_number', 'ID', 'value').plot()
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Perfect! I also have set a limit of 3 days. But how do I keep the same color on every ID? Because I need to perform a subplot from this dataframe and another one on the same way, and I need to keep a single color for df1 and another one for df2

Comment: I'm note sure I understand exactly what you want to do but you can specify the line colore in the `plot()` call like that: `df.pivot('ts_number', 'ID', 'value').plot(color=['red','green'])`

Comment: yes, I'm using the following code: `df.pivot('ts_number', 'ID', 'Value').plot(ax=ax,color='r')
df2.pivot('ts_number', ID', 'Value').plot(ax=ax,color='b')` to print one dataframe over the other one to perform some confronts. But now I don't know why on the y-axis instead of the value I'm getting the same rows as the x-axis. Do you know why?

Comment: Also, I noticed that with your first code my dataframe doesn't change the timestamps like in a resample, but simply created new ts_numbers. How do I do that without resampling also the IDs?

Comment: plotting works without problems for me: `ax = df.pivot('ts_number', 'ID', 'value').plot(color='red')`, `df2=df.copy()`, `df2.value += 5`, `df2.pivot('ts_number', 'ID', 'value').plot(ax=ax, color='green')`

Comment: still, in this code I'm getting the same values as the x-axis on the y-axis, and the df2's columns are the same as the one in df1

Comment: I don't know, for me it works well with this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pafs.png

Comment: for me the result is this one: as you can see, on the y I get the same values as x but I don't understand how's that possible: https://imgur.com/a/JOsnCKn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199203/discussion-between-erken-and-stef).